# how to add one column array to already existing array with shape 10000*17

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Please help me here, I am new to python. I am trying to add an array of one column to another array of shape `10000*17`. Below are the samples. Please help me to concatenate two arrays:

```py
 [[ 0.02061183, -0.90794402,  0.92005926, 0.5405426 , 4.85191978,  3.65479782],
   [-0.52203821, .50416184, -0.87750086, -0.625578  , -0.08879011, -0.57718519]]
```

I need to add a new row of array `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` to the above array.

Comment: not clear to me what you want...

Comment: Are these lists or numpy arrays.  The display looks like lists.`np.vstack` can join your (2,6) array with a (6,)

Comment: Your subject line does not fit with the rest of your question.  The "column array" has to have some dimension in common with the existing.  It would also help if you specified the desired shape of the result.  If you ask a confusing question you'll get confusing answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.insert(arr, i, the_object_to_be_added, axis)`:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = [[1, 2, 3],
             4, 5, 6]]

np.insert(my_array, 2, [7, 8, 9], axis=0)
# output my_array = [[1, 2, 3],
#                    [4, 5, 6],
#                    [7, 8, 9]]
```

or

```
my_array = [[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]]
np.insert(my_array, 1, [7, 8], axis=1)
# output my_array = [[1, 7, 2, 3],
#                    [4, 8, 5, 6]]
```